# What's wrong with the method returning an array of objects?

Tags: java

I cannot understand what is wrong with the code. The method returns an array of objects of Exam type. Method readAllExams extracts tokens from Scanner s and uses them to create Exam objects. The Exam objects are returned in an array.Can you help please?

```
public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, String examType, int score) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.examType = examType;
    this.score = score;
}

public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s) {
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    int ID = 0;
    String examType = "";
    int score = 0;

    Exam[] object = new Exam[5];

    while(s.hasNext()) {
        firstName = s.next();
        lastName = s.next();

        if(s.hasNextInt()) {
            ID = s.nextInt();
        } else {
            s.next();
        }

        examType = s.next();
        if(s.hasNextInt()) {
            score = s.nextInt();
        }

        object[] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examType, score);
        return object;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: You problem is probably because, if your code doesn't enter the while loop, you aren't returning nothing. After your while loop, you need to return an empty array or return null.

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: It's giving me an error in this line:  object[] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examType, score);

Comment: I think your problem is: you cannot assign an Exam object to an Exam[] array.

Comment: FORGOT TO PUT A QUESTION: IT'S GIVING ME AN ERROR IN    object[] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examType, score);

Comment: To add more informations in your question (like an actual question) use [edit] button placed below your post.

Comment: Not what you asked, but you seem to have a lot of calls to `s.next()`.  It may or may not be correct - without seeing your file format, it's impossible to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be:

```
public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s)
{
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    int ID = 0;
    String examType = "";
    int score = 0;

    Exam[] object = new Exam[5];

    int index = 0; //new added code
    while(s.hasNext())
    {
      //  ........... your code ..........

        object[index++] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examType, score); 
    }
    return object; //return should be out of while loop to return an array

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`object[]` is not a valid way to index an array.

In order to assign an element of an array, you need to know *which* element. For example, `object[0]` is the first element. `object[4]` is the 5th element. `object[index]` is the first element if `index` contains 0, the second element if `index` contains 1, the third element if `index` contains 2, etc...

When filling in an array, a common thing to do is to keep a counter storing which index you're currently filling in - for example: (with most of the code removed for brevity)

```
int currentIndex = 0;
while(...) {
    ...
    object[currentIndex] = ...;
    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1; // or currentIndex += 1; or currentIndex++;
}
```